# Code::Blocks crashea con process returned 0xC0000005

Tags: c++, codeblocks

Estoy haciendo un juego en C++ que consiste en una batalla Pokémon entre tres pokémones (Pikachu, Charmander y Squirtle). Caundo le doy play, aparece `Ataca Pikachu` y después aparece el cartel de "Pokémon.exe dejó de funcionar". Dejo el código del `main` y de las clases `Pokémons.h` y `Pikachu.h`. Toda ayuda es bienvenida. Gracias.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <list>
#include "Pokemons.h"
#include "Pikachu.h"
#include "Charmander.h"
#include "Squirtle.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Pokemons *pokemon;
    Pikachu  *pikachu = new Pikachu();
    Charmander *charmander = new Charmander();
    Squirtle *squirtle = new Squirtle();

    cout << pikachu->getNombre() << endl;
    cout << pikachu->getVida() << endl;
    cout << pikachu->getAtaque() << endl;
    cout << "\n" << endl;
    cout << charmander->getNombre() << endl;
    cout << charmander->getVida() << endl;
    cout << charmander->getAtaque() << endl;
    cout << "\n" << endl;
    cout << squirtle->getNombre() << endl;
    cout << squirtle->getVida() << endl;
    cout << squirtle->getAtaque() << endl;
    system("CLS");
    list<Pokemons*>* listaPokemons = new list<Pokemons*>;
    listaPokemons->push_back(pikachu);
    listaPokemons->push_back(charmander);
    listaPokemons->push_back(squirtle);
    Pokemons* objetivo;
    list<Pokemons*>::iterator pos;
    pos = listaPokemons->begin();

    while(objetivo->getVida() > 0)
    {
        cout << "Ataca " << (*pos)->getNombre() << endl;
        cout << "El pokemon " << objetivo->getNombre() << " recibe un ataque de " << (*pos)->atacar(objetivo) << " puntos" << endl;
        cout << "La vida de " << objetivo->getNombre() << " queda en " << objetivo->getVida() << " puntos" << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Ataca " << (*pos)->getNombre() << endl;
        cout << "El pokemon " << objetivo->getNombre() << " recibe un ataque de " << (*pos)->atacar(objetivo) << " puntos" << endl;
        cout << "La vida de " << objetivo->getNombre() << " queda en " << objetivo->getVida() << " puntos" << endl;
        cout << endl;
        pos++;

        if(pos == listaPokemons->end())
        {
            pos = listaPokemons->begin();
        }
    }

    delete objetivo;
    pos = listaPokemons->begin();

    while(pos != listaPokemons->end())
    {
        delete (*pos);
        pos++;
    }

    delete listaPokemons;
    return 0;
}
```

**Pokémons.h**

```
    #ifndef POKEMONS_H_INCLUDED
    #define POKEMONS_H_INCLUDED

    #include <string>

    class Pokemons
    {
    protected:
        std::string nombre;
        int vida;
        int ataque;

    public:
        std::string getNombre();
        int getVida();
        int getAtaque();
        virtual void recibirDanio(int) = 0;
        virtual ~Pokemons(){ };
        virtual int atacar(Pokemons* objetivo) = 0;
    };

    std::string Pokemons::getNombre()
    {
        return this->nombre;
    }

    int Pokemons::getVida()
    {
        return this->vida;
    }

    int Pokemons::getAtaque()
    {
        return this->ataque;
    }

    #endif // POKEMONS_H_INCLUDED
```

**Pikachu.h**

```
#ifndef PIKACHU_H_INCLUDED
#define PIKACHU_H_INCLUDED

#include <string>

class Pikachu: public Pokemons
{

public:

    Pikachu() {
        this->nombre = "Pikachu";
        this->vida = 100;
        this->ataque = 50;
    }

    void recibirDanio(int danio){
        this->vida -= danio/2;
    }

    virtual int atacar(Pokemons* target) {
        target->recibirDanio(this->ataque);
    }
};

#endif // PIKACHU_H_INCLUDED
```

NOTA 1: El código de los otros dos pokémones es idéntico ya que las tres clases heredan de la clase padre `Pokémones.h`.

NOTA 2: Hice un debug y me dice que el problema está en las líneas 41 (`main`) y 22 (`Pikachu.h`),

Comment: Este juego de Pokémon es superior al de Espada/Escudo. Este por lo menos trae a Squirtle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Caundo le doy play, aparece `Ataca Pikachu` y después aparece el cartel de "Pokémon.exe dejó de funcionar"

Lo sorprendente es que siquiera te muestre algún mensaje pues la instrucción anterior a tu primer mensaje ya es errónea:

```
Pokemons* objetivo;            // 'objetivo' está vacío
list<Pokemons*>::iterator pos; // 'pos' está vacío
pos = listaPokemons->begin();  // 'pos' apunta al primer elemento de 'listaPokemons' ('pikachu')

while(objetivo->getVida() > 0) // objetivo SIGUE VACÍO pero pides algo de su interior, debería fallar.
{
    cout << "Ataca " << (*pos)->getNombre() << endl;
```

El error `0xC0000005` se corresponde a un uso no válido de memoria, en concreto a memoria no inicializada… error al que es muy propenso tu código pues usas punteros en crudo si necesidad alguna de hacerlo. Te propongo ciertos cambios:

#### Propuesta.

```
// No uses el plural cuando te refieres a objetos.
class Pokemon
{
protected:
    // Inicializa los miembros como vacíos
    std::string nombre{};
    int vida{};
    int ataque{};

public:
    // Usa un constructor para asignar valores internos.
    Pokemon(std::string Nombre, int Vida, int Ataque) :
        nombre{Nombre}, vida{Vida}, ataque{Ataque}
    {}
    // La función no modifica el objeto: debe ser 'const'.
    // Puedes devolver una referencia constante al nombre, evitando copias de datos innecesarias.
    // Ya sabemos que estas leyendo el nombre, el 'get' es redundante (y mezcla idiomas).
    const std::string &Nombre() const
    {
        // No hay ningún otro 'nombre' aquí, el 'this->' es innecesario.
        return nombre;
    }
    // La función no modifica el objeto: debe ser 'const'.
    // Ya sabemos que estas leyendo la vida, el 'get' es redundante (y mezcla idiomas).
    int Vida() const
    {
        // No hay otra 'vida' aquí, el 'this->' es innecesario.
        return vida;
    }
    // La función no modifica el objeto: debe ser 'const'.
    // Ya sabemos que estas leyendo el ataque, el 'get' es redundante (y mezcla idiomas).
    int Ataque() const
    {
        // No hay otro 'ataque' aquí, el 'this->' es innecesario.
        return vida;
    }
    virtual void recibirDanio(int) = 0;
    // Si el cuerpo del destructor va a estar vacío, deja que el compilador se ocupe.
    virtual ~Pokemon() = default;
    // Evita los punteros, usa referencias.
    virtual void atacar(Pokemon& objetivo) = 0;
};
```

```
// Si todos los miembros van a ser públicos, valora usar una struct
struct Pikachu: public Pokemon
{
    // Llama al constructor de la clase base
    Pikachu() : Pokemon{"Pikachu", 100, 50}
    {}

    void recibirDanio(int danio) {
        // No hay otra 'vida' aquí, el 'this->' es innecesario.
        vida -= danio/2;
    }

    // No pretendes sobrecargar más esta función, el 'virtual' es innecesario.
    // Pretendes sobrecargar la función base, no olvides el 'override'
    // Evita los punteros, usa referencias.
    // No devuelves ningún valor, la función debería ser 'void'.
    void atacar(Pokemon& target) override {
        // No hay otro 'ataque' aquí, el 'this->' es innecesario.
        target.recibirDanio(ataque);
    }
};
```

```
int main()
{
    // No necesitas memoria dinámica para crear la lista.
    // Puedes crear los Pokémon al mismo tiempo que la lista
    list<Pokemon*> listaPokemons
    {
        new Pikachu, new Charmander, new Squirtle
    };

    // Puedes listar con bucles lo que tienes en la lista, en lugar de uno a uno
    for (const auto &pokemon : listaPokemons)
    {
        // Un solo 'cout' es suficiente
        cout << pokemon->Nombre() << '\n'
             << pokemon->Vida() << '\n'
             << pokemon->Ataque() << '\n'
             // Si solo imprimes un carácter, no uses un literal de cadena.
             // un 'endl' por llamada es suficiente.
             << '\n' << endl;
    }

    // … hacer cosas    

    // Puedes borrar el contenido de la lista con otro sencillo bucle:
    for (const auto &pokemon : listaPokemons)
        delete pokemon;    

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Probé tu propuesta y me tira los errores `conflicting return type specified for 'virtual void Pikachu::Atacar(Pokemon&)'` y `overriding 'virtual int Pokemon::Atacar(Pokemon&)'`.

Comment: Eso es porque me despisté al escribir la propuesta: tanto la función base como la derivada deben tener el mismo tipo de retorno. Esa es la *gracia* de usar `override`, que te avisa si no estás sobrescribiendo la función adecuadamente.

Comment: En el `for` que lista el contenido de `listaPokemons` me tira el error `expected primary-expression before '->' token` en el `cout`.

Comment: Algo estás haciendo de manera diferente @Unknown6147 , ya que por lo que puedo ver [el código no da errores de compilación](https://wandbox.org/permlink/LdbBE9ZyEWK006Ar).

Answer (score 3):

El problema que veo en código es que declaras un puntero pero nunca lo inicializa.  El código de el siguiente:

```cpp
    Pokemons* objetivo;
```

Observa que la declaración anterior no inicializa la variable, por lo tanto, va a  tomar como dirección a un objeto `Pokemons` al valor que en ese momento tenga.

Más adelante utilizas esta variable en el `while`:

```cpp
    list<Pokemons*>::iterator pos;
    pos = listaPokemons->begin();

    while(objetivo->getVida() > 0)
```

Cuando no inicializa un puntero este tiene cualquier dirección de memoria, por lo tanto,  sea donde sea que apunte va a tratar de invocar a `getVida()`utilizando el desplazamiento a esta función, pero como es  `bool` quizá entre al `while`, pero no creo que salga de este con vida.  Allí puede suceder cualquier cosa, hasta tumbarse al equipo.

Siempre que utilices punteros inicializalo a NULO ya que de esta forma el error será por puntero nulo. Trabajar con punteros en c++ es bien riesgoso. Te recomendaria que utilices los `Smart pointers` de la STL.

La verdad, no conozco mucho de `Pokemon` por lo que no sabría decirte a que objeto debería apuntar.